# Entity Framework Core - Disconnected update of entity with multiple navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project that uses EF Core and I'm having some massive issues with updating data.

My data structure (simplified) looks like so:

```
public class Event
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public List<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public List<Slot> Slots {get;set;}
}

public class Slot
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public Channel? Channel {get;set;}
     public Pilot? Pilot {get;set;}
}
```

`Pilot` and `Channel` classes only have Ids and some simple properties

My context's `OnModelCreating` looks like so:

```
modelBuilder
     .Entity<Event>()
     .HasMany(r => r.Groups);

modelBuilder
     .Entity<Group>()
     .HasMany(r => r.Slots);
```

Pretty much all operations on all of these collections are permitted, a group can be added/updated/deleted, it can have one or multiple slots that can also be added/updated/deleted, slots can have `Pilot` and `Channel` fields, but they also may be nulls.

I'm running into issues when trying to update the `Event` object. In my case it's a disconnected update, because different contexts will download and update the data. I had pretty much all possible issues from `Groups` not being added/deleted, through `Slots` not being added/deleted and my latest issue is that when I'm updating a `Slot` and setting its `Pilot` to anything, including null, the `PilotId` column in DB (generated by EF) doesn't update.

My current update method looks like this (please, for the love of god, don't roast me for how it looks, I spent 4 hours trying to get at least a POC that works so I can then refactor it into something useable)

```
   public void UpdateEvent(Event ev)
        {
            using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

            var dbEvent = context.Event
                .Include(e => e.RegisteredPilots)
                .Include(e => e.Groups).ThenInclude(e => e.Slots).ThenInclude(e => e.Channel)
                .Include(e => e.Groups).ThenInclude(e => e.Slots).ThenInclude(e => e.Pilot)
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == ev.Id);

            var pilots = context.Pilot.ToList();
            var channels = context.VtxChannel.ToList();

            context.MergeCollections(dbEvent.RegisteredPilots, ev.RegisteredPilots, p => p.Id);

            foreach (var group in ev.Groups)
            {
                var dbGroup = dbEvent.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == group.Id);

                group.Event = dbEvent;
                foreach (var slot in group.Slots)
                {
                    if (slot.Pilot != null)
                        slot.Pilot = pilots.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == slot.Pilot.Id);

                    if (slot.Channel != null)
                        slot.Channel = channels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == slot.Channel.Id);
                }

                if (dbGroup != null)
                    context.MergeCollections(dbGroup.Slots, group.Slots, p => p.Id, true);
            }

            context.MergeCollections(dbEvent.Groups, ev.Groups, p => p.Id, true);

            context.Update(dbEvent);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The `MergeCollections` method is an extension method that I found in some old AF article, it helped a bit, but it's still not working properly. It looks like this:

```
public static void MergeCollections<T, TKey>(this DbContext context, ICollection<T> currentItems, ICollection<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> keyFunc, bool deleteObsolete = false)
    where T : class
        {
            List<T> toRemove = null;
            foreach (var item in currentItems)
            {
                var currentKey = keyFunc(item);
                var found = newItems.FirstOrDefault(x => currentKey.Equals(keyFunc(x)));
                if (found == null)
                {
                    toRemove ??= new List<T>();
                    toRemove.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(found, item))
                    {
                        context.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(found);
                        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in toRemove)
                {
                    currentItems.Remove(item);
                    if (deleteObsolete)
                        context.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            foreach (var newItem in newItems)
            {
                var newKey = keyFunc(newItem);
                var found = currentItems.FirstOrDefault(x => newKey.Equals(keyFunc(x)));
                if (found == null)
                {
                    currentItems.Add(newItem);
                    context.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry for slamming you with a wall of text and code, but I'm on the 4th stage of grief and just need any help.

I can't think of any other way of updating all of this data other than updating it through the `Event` object.

What would be the correct way to do this? All articles/tutorials that I can find on this topic are from 7 years ago and contain some obsolete methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first the disclaimer: Working with detached entities is expensive and complicated. Best advice, just don't do it, but you've done it so now how to deal with it.

The good news is that your code is quite easy to follow so for all that frustration it's not "that bad" but there are a few issues and improvements you can make.

First, lets look at the merge collections. Depending on where these detached entities are coming from, I do not recommend doing things this way with attaching entities and setting their state to modified. For instance if this passed in entity/collection was deserialized from a view through an MVC controller action, you may expect a copy of the original entity with just changes you allowed, but you may run into scenarios where the data coming back isn't complete (I.e. new values the view didn't need to update are introduced but not given Hidden columns so come back as default, or tampered data where the call back is intercepted such as with browser debugging tools and altered) Copying all fields across cart-blanche or attaching a detached instance and setting the state to Modified risks unintended or malicious overwrites happening.

```
public static void MergeCollections<T, TKey>(this DbContext context, ICollection<T> currentItems, ICollection<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> keyFunc, bool deleteObsolete = false)
    where T : class
    {
        List<T> toRemove = new();
        foreach (var item in currentItems)
        {
            var currentKey = keyFunc(item);
            var found = newItems.FirstOrDefault(x => currentKey.Equals(keyFunc(x)));
            if (found == null)
            {
                toRemove ??= new List<T>();
                toRemove.Add(item);
            }
            else if (!ReferenceEquals(found, item))
            {
                //context.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(found);
                UpdateMapper.Map(item, found);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in toRemove)
        {
            currentItems.Remove(item);
            if (deleteObsolete)
                context.Remove(item);
        }

        foreach (var newItem in newItems)
        {
            var newKey = keyFunc(newItem);
            //Somewhat redundant check...
            var found = currentItems.Any(x => newKey.Equals(keyFunc(x)));
            if (found)
                currentItems.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

The main differences I would suggest here would be to use Automapper's `Map(from,to)` method with a mapping configuration set up with the rules as to what values are allowed to be copied across when updating an entity. Normally when working with ViewModels or DTOs to Entities, a single Automapper configuration can be set up since the DTO would only contain the data that is actually allowed to be changed. When dealing with detached entities we may want to use a dedicated "Update" mapper that is set up to ignore possible differences in fields coming in that we absolutely do not intend to be changed. For instance when updating an OrderItem we might allow the Quantity to be changed, and have rules to ensure that it is > 0, but we absolutely don't want things like a CreatedByUserId or CreatedAtDateTime value to be altered etc. Automapper is a better choice to help ensure only what we expect to be changed can be changed vs. `SetValues` which will overwrite everything. This also means that if we are updating values on a tracked entity we do not need to set the Entity State. The change tracker will build an UPDATE statement for just the values that change if something has actually changed, where EntityState.Modified will generate an UPDATE statement for all columns regardless of whether anything actually changed or not.

Next looking at the main UpdateEvent method. These lines can possibly be optimized:

```
 var pilots = context.Pilot.ToList();
 var channels = context.VtxChannel.ToList();
```

It would depend on how many pilots and channels you have, but rather than loading the entire table, you can load just the ones you need:

```
var pilotIds = ev.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Slots.Select(s => s.Pilot.Id)).Distinct().ToList();
var channelIds = ev.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Slots.Select(s => s.Channel.id)).Distinct().ToList();

var pilots = context.Pilot
    .Where(p => pilotIds.Contains(p.Id))
    .ToList();
var channels = context.VtxChannel
    .Where(c => channelIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .ToList();
```

This would just fetch the pilots and channels actually requested for the updated event. Again, if we are talking about 10's of rows in the table, this wouldn't be necessary, but something to consider for larger tables.

The next thing would be to avoid using the `FirstOrDefault` unless not finding it is handled. It's better to use 'First' if an item not found is an exceptional case. This way the error point will be more obvious. In your example code it's not a breaker, but it's easy to fall onto a crutch of "OrDefault" where potentially exceptional null references get passed into methods as arguments or used in a bigger expression, resulting in a NullReferenceException where you're left picking through which reference was possibly #null.

Lastly, you don't need the `Update()` method at the end as you are updating tracked entities with the contents of the detached, untracked ones. Just call `SaveChanges()` and EF will work out what statements to build based on the change tracking. `Update` is used in cases where you want to tell EF to overwrite a data record with a detached entity.

Other than that, this looks about fine, but as you can see, updating detached entities is a fair bit of work so there isn't a lot of value to be had by passing entities around. The next step is instead just defining DTOs/ViewModels to project from entities to views/consumers, and accepting those DTOs back to fetch entity graphs and Map values across from the DTO. The advantages of using projected DTOs instead of passing entity graphs is that you can optimize queries to return only the fields your consumer needs, which also reduces the payload size travelling between server and client and back. It also reduces the need to second guess whether an entity passed into a method is a tracked, or detached entity.

Comment: Attaching an entity and setting "modified" is the same as _blindly replacing all values_. If you have audit tracing on it will look like all fields were modified, even if potentially _none_ of them were! This is a good answer, but it's still only the start of your journey, as a community, can we please remove the examples that lead to developers attaching entities!

Comment: I'd probably avoid introducing AutoMapper in this way, SetValues is the same as AutoMapper setting all fields. Its a good idea, but takes a lot more setup than you have explained here to make it work in the way we intend.

Comment: Also, only 1 of the `FirstOrDefaults()` were questionable. The information you have provided is useful in general regarding  _OrDefault()_ but not necessary in this context because OP was using it relatively better than most ;), the last check is only redundant if you trust that the caller was doing the right thing.

Comment: There is no example given using "Attach", only a warning not to use it /w EntityState.Modified. I recommend Automapper rather than SetValues as Automapper can be configured to explicitly map only desired values and ignore the rest. (`.ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());`) As for FirstOrDefault there were three problematic ones. Firstly getting the Event itself, then getting the Pilot and Channel to substitute. The recommendation is a warning not to "default" to *OrDefault(). :)

Comment: I meant outside of this post, someone else is teaching people the wrong way to update entities using Attach... Modified, it lets the framework and our whole community down because people see it is EF being slow when it's just badly written code.

Comment: Thank you for a response and comments, I made a POC using my own mapping methods and I got it to work properly. May consider using Automapper if my entities grow a bit more. Yeah, you're right about disconnected updates being kind of a nuisance. It's not too late in my project to change things up. What, in your opinion, would currently be the best way to handle data with EF? (I mean a very high level overview)

Comment: IMO the best way to use EF is to leverage projection when reading data (`Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo`) and then resisting the urge to try and hide/restrict EF behind abstractions. Sometimes the justification is to make it so EF could be swapped out later which ends up a self-fulfilling prophecy as the straightjacket abstractions just make EF slow and complicated. The other reason for abstraction is to standardize or "dumb down" an interface for other developers, again often crippling what you can do when a better investment is upskilling Jr. devs in getting the most from EF.